# Many-to-many relationship throw an error after updating to Entity Framework 6

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have "many-to-many relationship", which worked perfectly on a local machine until it was time to move to  a server. During the move a runtime error was thrown. After upgrade to Entity Framework 6 it worked, but... One of the "many-to-many relationship" was broken.

Models have many properties and they looks something like this:

```
public partial class CartItem
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ProductOptionValue> ProductOptionValues { get; set; }
}
public class CartItemMapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<CartItem>
{
    public CartItemMapping() : base()
    {
        this.HasMany(e => e.ProductOptionValues).WithMany(e => e.CartItems)
            .Map(e => e.ToTable("CartItemOptions").MapLeftKey("productOptionValueId").MapRightKey("cartItemId"));
    }
}

public class ProductOptionValue
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<CartItem> CartItems { get; set; }
}
public class ProductOptionValueMapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<ProductOptionValue>
{
    public ProductOptionValueMapping() : base()
    {
        this.HasMany(e => e.CartItems).WithMany(e => e.ProductOptionValues)
            .Map(e => e.ToTable("CartItemOptions").MapLeftKey("cartItemId").MapRightKey("productOptionValueId"));
    }
}
```

When getting earlier saved CartItems, ProductOptionValues has count = 0 and there is no way to save a new one.

I found this question on another forum, and only answer was that, this relationship will not work after update at all. But maybe there is a solution?

Or maybe some idea why runtime error was thrown on server with Entity Framework 5?

**EDIT**

Errors:

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
> "FK_CartItem_CartItemOptions". The conflict occurred in database
> "database", table "dbo.CartItems", column 'id'. The statement has been
> terminated.
>
> An error occurred while saving entities that do not expose foreign key
> properties for their relationships. The EntityEntries property will
> return null because a single entity cannot be identified as the source
> of the exception. Handling of exceptions while saving can be made
> easier by exposing foreign key properties in your entity types. See the InnerException for details.

Comment: how did you save the `CartItems` ? could you post the code when saving `CartItems` ?

Comment: I save whole model db.CartItems.Add(CartItem)

Comment: the tables and the configurations seem fine, perhaps there is something wrong with the data manipulation